# Stack in java not working properly?

Tags: java, stack

I am trying to store data into the stack.Correct me if I am wrong, stack is a Last in, first out type. So, was expecting that the output of my program will be kinda reverse. But sad to say the output is different. I am not sure what part of the codes is wrong.

Please help :|

CODE:

`

public class CorruptQueue
{

```
public static void LineUp(){

    BufferedReader br = null;

try {

    String line;
    Stack nameStack = new Stack();
    Stack statusStack = new Stack();
    Stack stack = new Stack();

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/user/Desktop/School Files/Project/CorruptOffice/input.txt"));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


       StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");

       while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {


        String lineup = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        String name = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();
        String status = stringTokenizer.nextElement().toString();



            nameStack.push(name);
            statusStack.push(status);
            System.out.println("Now serving "+ nameStack.pop() + " a " + statusStack.pop());



        /*StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("" + lineup);
        sb.append(" " + name);
        sb.append("" + status);
        sb.append("\n\n");

        System.out.println(sb.toString());*/
       }

    }

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (br != null)
            br.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    }



public static void main(String[] args) 
{
     LineUp();
```

}
}`

INPUT:

lineup John regular

lineup Bob regular

lineup Tom regular

lineup Sarah VIP

lineup Marie VIP

lineup Joan VIP

lineup Bea VIP

lineup Hank regular

lineup Art regular

lineup Daisy VIP

lineup Marius regular

lineup Dane VIP

OUTPUT:

Now serving John a regular

Now serving Bob a regular

Now serving Tom a regular

Now serving Sarah a VIP

Now serving Marie a VIP

Now serving Joan a VIP

Now serving Bea a VIP

Now serving Hank a regular

Now serving Art a regular

Now serving Daisy a VIP

Now serving Marius a regular

Now serving Dane a VIP

Done

Comment: Is your input in the order that you put it in? ie You pushed John, then Bob.. or is that what the stack looks like?

Answer (score 8):

your stack operations seem to be here

```
nameStack.push(name);
statusStack.push(status);
System.out.println("Now serving "+ nameStack.pop() + " a " + statusStack.pop());
```

Now your stack would be reversing the names if you pushed them all before you started popping anything, but you're pushing and popping at the same time for 1 item at a time.

so in essence, you push `name` and `status` onto the stack, but before you do antying else, you just pop them back off and print them to the console.

Your stack isn't really doing anything.

---

If you actually want to reverse your output, take

```
System.out.println("Now serving "+ nameStack.pop() + " a " + statusStack.pop());
```

out of your initial loop, and then put it in a new loop.

Answer (score 5):

```
  nameStack.push(name);
  statusStack.push(status);
  System.out.println("Now serving "+ nameStack.pop() + " a " + statusStack.pop());
```

OK. So, you are saying, push a name onto the stack. And then immediately pop that name from the stack. So, yes, it is LIFO, but you only ever have ONE element on your stack. Try moving the pop operations completely outside your while loop. Then have another while loop that keeps popping elements until your stack  is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has this section:

```
 nameStack.push(name);
 statusStack.push(status);
 System.out.println("Now serving "+ nameStack.pop() + " a " + statusStack.pop());
```

As you push a value onto the stack, you pop it straight off again! You should push them all on, then pop them off after all of them are on.

It might be worth [reading up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) on stacks a little bit more, just to make sure you understand them :)

Comment: TBH, I don't think the OP's problem is in understanding stacks, but rather understanding basic step-by-step program flow.

Comment: We all make silly mistakes from time to time I guess. If OP is onto data structures like stacks, I imagine they have a pretty good grasp of program flow. Either way, the question was answered. :)